# DBeaver 6.2.1 stopped working on my Ubuntu 19.04 after I tried installing php-mysql

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, dbeaver

I just switched to Linux from Windows and was trying to setup LAMP stack on my system. I installed DBeaver as my mysql client. I made a connection to the localhost with the default settings and it worked perfect.
But while working with PHP mysqli functions were giving me errors. After a little bit of Googling online I found out i had forgot to install php-mysql. After installing it mysqli functions started working but DBeaver started to give me the following errors:

- Communications link failure
- The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
  ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
- Connection refused (Connection refused)

I think I broke something while trying to get mysqli functions to work. I tried to make a new connection but it gave me the same error. I also tried to uninstall(purge) DBeaver and reinstalled it but but the old connections were still there along with the error. 
[image: image for reference]

PS: I'm very very new to Linux so I'd be very grateful if you could give me a step-by-step solution. Thank you.

Comment: Try with PORT 33060.  [Look here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-port-reference/en/mysql-ports-reference-tables.html)

Comment: If you open a terminal (CRTL+ALT+T) and try to connect to mySQL with command `mysql -u root -p`, does it work?

Comment: @FloT Yes mysql -u root -p . I also started to use phpmyadmin for now(which I previously used with windows) and it is working fine. I don't understand the issue with DBeaver.

Comment: On your screenshot, I can see that you tried with the JDBC driver for MySQL 8+. Does it match your installed mySQL version? If not, would you try with another JDBC driver?